# How do i put text below a div tag?

Tags: html, css

I have used divs to make two images both sides of a table, however once the divs have ended the text i input with `<p>` appear above the divs despite being later in the code. I want the text to appear below the table.
here is my code.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="website.css"/>
<title> Stoge Guitars </title>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "container">
    <div id = "X">
        <img src= "images/workshop.png" id = "guitar">
    </div>
    <div id = "C">  
        <img src= "images/workshop.png" id = "guitar2">
    </div>
    <div id = "V">  
        <table>
        <tr>
            <th colspan = "5" id = "STOGEGUITARS"> STOGE GUITARS </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Home</th>
            <th>Our Custom Guitars</th>
            <th>Forum</th>
            <th>Workshop Gallery</th>
            <th>Contact Us</th>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </div>
<p> This should be below the table </p> 
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body
{
Background-image:     url("http://images.epiphone.com.s3.amazonaws.com/Products/Les-Paul/Les-Paul- Standard-Plustop-PRO/Gallery/POP_LPSTDPLUSPRO-HB.jpg");
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
#STOGEGUITARS
{
font-size: 20pt;
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-style: italic;
}
table, th, td
{
border: 1px solid black;
}
table
{
width: 60%;
margin-left: 20%;
margin-right: 20%;
position: fixed;
}
#guitar
{
float: left;
 }
#guitar2
 {
float: right;   
}
 #guitar
{
width: 19%;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
 }
 #guitar2
{
width: 19%;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
 right: 0px;
}
p
{
border: 0px;
text-align: left;
}
```

Help will be greatly appreciated thanks. Sorry if i've made a silly mistake, i am only 16 and new to HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your both HTML and CSS code:

```css
body {
  Background-image:     url("http://images.epiphone.com.s3.amazonaws.com/Products/Les-Paul/Les-Paul- Standard-Plustop-PRO/Gallery/POP_LPSTDPLUSPRO-HB.jpg");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin:0;
}

#STOGEGUITARS {
  font-size: 20pt;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-style: italic;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  width:100%;
}

#X {
  display:inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  width: 19%;
  height: 100%;
}

#V {
  margin:0;
  display:inline-block;
  top:0px;
  width: 62%;
  height: 100%;   
  border:1px solid red; /* Remove this line it's just for checking boundaries  */
}

#C {
  display:inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  right:0px;
  top:0px;
  width: 19%;
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

p {
  position:relative;
  text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<center>
<div id = "container">
    <div id = "X">
        <img src= "https://fedoraproject.org/w/uploads/6/66/Artwork_F9Themes_Shoowa_shoowa-horizontal.png" id = "guitar" />
    </div>
    <div id = "V">  
        <table>
        <tr>
            <th colspan = "5" id = "STOGEGUITARS"> STOGE GUITARS </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Home</th>
            <th>Our Custom Guitars</th>
            <th>Forum</th>
            <th>Workshop Gallery</th>
            <th>Contact Us</th>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <p> This should be below the table </p>
    </div>
    <div id = "C">  
        <img src= "https://fedoraproject.org/w/uploads/6/66/Artwork_F9Themes_Shoowa_shoowa-horizontal.png" id = "guitar2" />
    </div>
    </div>
</center>
```

Answer (score 1):

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m37hy4ay/)

```
position: relative;
```

is what you're looking for, position fixed makes other elements ignore the position of the element

Answer (score -1):

Just literally put a  right under the  you wanna put something under it
Did it just now and it worked! :D

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35285870)